# How to build a generic method to connect the notifySignal of different Q_PROPERTY types to a void slot(QVariant) from the property char * name?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots, qproperty

I'm trying to write a method, with two parameters : the `Q_PROPERTY` name (`char *`) and the `QObject *` associated with, that permit to connect the notifySignal (if exists) of the `Q_PROPERTY`, to a `void slot(QVariant)`, or to a slot dynamically builded which will call a `void method(QVariant)`. The signature of the signal can vary according to the type of the parameter.

How can I achieve that in Qt 5? Maybe it's impossible, but I will not stop searching while I'm not sure of that.

So I think I have 3 solutions:

- building dynamically a slot of the exact signature of the signal, from the signal name, and call a method(QVariant) in it, using the old Qt connect way:

  ```
  connect(sender, SIGNAL (valueChanged(QString,QString)),
      receiver, SLOT (updateValue(QString)) );
  ```
- using the new Qt 5 connect system:

  ```
  connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged,receiver, &Receiver::updateValue );
  ```
- building all slots signatures that can be used with QVariant.

Althougt, I don't know how to build a slot dynamically that call a specified method for the first solution ; I don't know how to retrieve the function pointer from the `QMetaMethod` of the notifySignal, for the second solution ; maybe the last solution is the best way, and easy to achieve, but it seams a bit extreme.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

For "building a slot dynamically" there are private APIs in Qt (look for QMetaObjectBuilder or similar classes). However that doesn't solve the problem of the connection.

Note that `QObject::connect` is overloaded to take `QMetaMethod`s as signals and slots. So you can easily build a "receiver" class object (for the only purpose of remembering which property it's acting upon):

```
class Receiver : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Receiver(const char *property, QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent),
        m_property(property)
    {}

signals:
    void propertyChangedForObject(const char *property, QObject *object);
public slots:
    void onPropertyChanged() {
        emit propertyChangedForObject(m_property, sender());
    }
private:
   const char * const m_property;
};
```

And hook it up in your method.